# Click not registered if element position changed onmousedown

Tags: html, css, onclick

I just discovered this strange problem on an `<a>` element. I wanted to make a css only button with a "pushed down" animation.

More or less something like this:

```
.button:active {
position: relative;
top: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that link doesn't seem to work if you do the mousedown below the text and release when the text has moven below the pointer (the animation runs correctly but onclick or href don't work). You can see the "bug" or whatever it is in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9RgD/

I already tried different things, like using padding to create the animation but it still doesn't work. I can confirm it doesn't in Chrome 22 (latest version as of today). Why does this happen? How can I get around this problem to animate a css only button?

Comment: I'm not seeing any different behavior when clicking below the text. I tested in IE9 and Firefox 16. Both "shift" the element to the active state. IE9 put up a blank alert box on click, and Firefox did not ([so I added content to the alert](http://jsfiddle.net/6bEq8/2/), then that worked also).

Comment: @ScottS That is the answer, Firefox will throw a NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.alert] if you call alert() without any arguments.

Comment: @Willem--maybe. But the OP did not say what browser, and for me it made no difference whether clicking on the text or under the text, so I don't know if that is really the issue.

Comment: The problem isn't with the CSS and the active state. The animation does work, but the click is not registered in many browser versions. Including the latest Chrome (22.something)

Comment: Also about the `alert()`, an `<a>` element with an href doesn't work either. I used an alert only so it could be tested without redirecting somewhere.

Comment: Okay, I confirm Chrome is having the issue you describe for me as well.

Comment: I cannot corroborate it happens in which browsers it happens, I only have Firefox 3.6 and it does.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot answer "why" (I think it may be a bug). It seems like I recall encountering a similar issue before with Chrome, and came up with a similar workaround as I offer here. Somehow, adding the "overlay" of the pseudo-element causes the whole to become "clickable." In your case, I noticed that if I clicked toward the top of the `div`, it also did not register, but when I added the `top` adjustment to the `:before` in the `:active` state, that seemed to be resolved also.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bEq8/9/) seems to have a working solution. HTML is the same as your fiddle (except I added the content to the alert):

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs-container">
<div onclick="alert('here')">Click below the text</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```css
.tabs-container div{
    display: inline-block;
    background: whitesmoke;    
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
    position: relative;
}

.tabs-container div:active{
    top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.tabs-container div:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.tabs-container div:active:before {
    top: -10px;
}
```

​